# rsync в Python. Получение списка синхронизированных файлов

Tags: python, rsync, glob

```
query = 'rsync -zavP server@10.10.0.160:/home/server/Catalog/ /home/user/sample'
os.popen(query)
os.chdir('/home/user/sample')
files = glob.glob(*.*)
```

Rsync прекрасно работает. Файлы копируются, при этом в директории user создается поддиректория sample, которой до этого не было. Но, что при попытке получить список файлов он оказывается пуст. Нужно получить список файлов. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы забыли подождать окончания копирования. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: Или https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system.

Comment: Спасибо, да проблема именно в этом.